# How to deploy node js in windows server 2012

Tags: node.js, api, iis-8, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows 2012 server and **hello world** node js file (Only one js file along with Node_module folder).

Now I need to deploy it to the windows server and need to run it globally.

How to do that? Please help me!

I have read more article. But confused. I installed Node app on the server. I ran it locally. It is working. But How to do it globally. ([www.xxxx.com/ABC](http://www.xxxx.com/ABC))

Comment: Hi @sankaran! Do you mean you would like to access the app on the internet or an internal network?  
  
If you're serving the Node.js application over HTTP using something like Express, you can navigate to the application using another computer on the same network with **http://<ipaddressofyourserver>:<port>** (if your ports are open).  
  
However, you may want to look into hosting your app with IIS and getting a domain name. There are a lot of variables and context is key here. I think we need some more information about what you're doing/trying to achieve in order to help you further.

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

- [iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode). There are a few more configuration steps with this option, but there seems to be additional benefits.
- [allow port through Windows Firewall](https://coderwall.com/p/mbov6w/running-nodejs-and-express-on-windows), the post is self explanatory.

### iisnode

Some resources:

- https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-custom-web.config-for-Node-apps
- I picked up a few pointers from [Hosting Node.js Applications on Windows Server 2012, Complete with Git Deployment and Remote Debugging - Part 2](http://codetunnel.com/hosting-nodejs-applications-on-windows-server-2012-complete-with-git-deployment-and-remote-debugging-part-2/)

Comment: Hello there. May I ask, is issnode still a valid option? Because most tutorials about it are from 2011-2013. Furthermore, my node is version 8. Also, what if I install node with issnode and then want to deploy angular on that node? Thanks

Comment: I last tried `iisnode` with node v6.x, and it worked. iisnode is just the means by which one can host node applications on iis.